# reffMedium returns empty string. What is wrong

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm new in JS and I'm having issues with the code found below.

The problem is that `reffMedium` returns `""` :

```
var reffCookie = 'adwords';
var reffCookieArray = reffCookie.split('|');
var reffLastNdSource = reffCookieArray[reffCookieArray.length - 1];
var reffSource;
var reffMedium;
var reffCampaign;

if (reffLastNdSource.includes("direct")) {
    reffSource = 'direct';
    reffMedium = 'none.';
    reffCampaign = '';

} else if (reffLastNdSource.includes("adwords")) {
    reffSource = 'google';
    reffMedium = 'cpc';
    reffCampaign = '';

} else if (reffLastNdSource.includes("www.google.com")) {
    reffSource = 'google';
    reffMedium = 'organic';
    reffCampaign = '';

} else if (reffLastNdSource.includes("campaign"))
    reffSource = reffLastNdSource.substring(
        reffLastNdSource.lastIndexOf("s:[") + 1,
        reffLastNdSource.lastIndexOf("]")
    );

reffMedium = reffLastNdSource.substring(
    reffLastNdSource.lastIndexOf("m:[") + 1,
    reffLastNdSource.lastIndexOf("]s:[")
);

reffCampaign = reffLastNdSource.substring(
    reffLastNdSource.lastIndexOf("c:[") + 1,
    reffLastNdSource.lastIndexOf("]m:[")
);

document.getElementById('reff_source').value = reffSource;
document.getElementById('reff_medium').value = reffMedium;
document.getElementById('reff_medium').value = reffCampaign;
```

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try and output

```
reffLastNdSource
```

And see the actual value to try and understand why it is returning ""

I simply think it is not meeting any of the conditions in your if statements.

Comment: The problem is that reffSource is returned with the correct value. So If condition works, but the second variable returns empty.